# How can I combine static and fluid layout with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I really like the fluid layout of Bootstrap, with one exception. It is very inconvenient to have sidebars shrink, since sidebars usually contain navigation or help content that looks bad when resized. Is there a way to lock sidebar to one size, while allowing the rest of the interface to be fluid?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by adding a min-width/max-width to the concerned column?

Comment: Doesn't work. Min-width breaks floating and so the content falls down.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean, but it's probably not worth the trouble of doing. Either pick a fully fluid layout, or a fully fixed-width layout.

Otherwise you would most likely use a JavaScript solution to calculate the width of the content by subtracting the sidebar width from the page.  I'm not really sure of another way to do this with just CSS since one would be a static pixel value and the other would be a percentage.